# ngrok blocked by Fortinet FortiGuard

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, ngrok, webfiltering, advanced-threat-protection

I would like to use ngrok for Microsoft Teams app development but it's being blocked by our FortiGuard threat protection and I cannot create a tunnel with the standard command ngrok http 80.

What do I tell our FortiGuard admin that needs to be changed in order to allow ngrok to work?

Thanks.

Comment: hmm, at time it happens. In such scenario, you may need to talk to your administrator to see how to enable the ports required for NGROK. You may want to get it [started from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395129/how-does-ngrok-work-behind-a-firewall).

Comment: Will move this to answer. Consider accept it as answer, upvote the answer. So it can be useful to others as well :)

Answer (score 5):

@colonel_claypoo If your problem persists, Can you check if you can use
[tunnelrelay](https://github.com/officeDev/microsoft-teams-tunnelrelay) (Refer the URL) instead of ngrok.

Answer (score 0):

In such scenario, you may need to talk to your administrator to see how to enable the ports required for NGROK. You may want to [get it started from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395129/how-does-ngrok-work-behind-a-firewall)